# Different Apple Certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I am creating my apple developer certificates - just redoing them to have a clean up.

I can create both my developer and my distribution certificates fine, however they have a different name.

Will this affect the final product?

The reason I am doing a clean up is that it kept giving me errors about not matching certificates.

Any advice would be great:-)
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distribution certificate` have the name of your company and the `developer certificate` have your name.

You have to use `distribution certificates` to release program in app store or create ad-hoc program and the developer is only to compile and run in iPhone/iPad.

But, by `name`you are saying the `identifier` you can use the same for both certificates or create, like I do, 2 different, than the app store program will not overwrite your dev program.

Comment: Cool that makes sense - now I am not so annoyed about it anymore:-)